# RTK: How to run refetch after mutation success

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to call refetch function after the mutation succeded:

```js
 const [joinTeam ] = useJoinTeamMutation();
 const { refetch } = useGetTeam(slugName);
```

I tried doing:

```js
joinTeam().then((res: any) => {
     if (!res.error) {
          refetch();
     }
});
```

but this causes an error: `Cannot refetch a query that has not been started yet.`

Comment: Your question has got an issue. You showed us `joinTeam` then you used `leaveTeam` function!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is builtin using tags, no need for promises check the docs [Automatic refetch](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching)